# How can I dynamically generate/draw a UI in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an in-memory representation of a basic tree structure. I want to dynamically generate a representation of this tree structure in the UI and allow users to click on nodes to reveal (text-based) details about the node. The UI would conist of icons for node types linked via branches. How would you suggest I approach this? All the UI elements I have worked with are statically defined in XML res files so I'm not sure where to begin..

thanks